# Google Sheets - Get unique values from a column and return the values a single column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I was hoping to get some help and direction. I have two sheets--a 'Raw data' sheet and a 'Dashboard' sheet. A user would dump the raw data in the first sheet and the dashboard will summarise figures automatically (built some scripts for it).

In the 'Raw Data' sheet, there is a column for Teams which contain the names of the different teams a user is a part of (screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of raw data]

**Job to be done:** I would like to get the list of unique teams from this column excluding the blank ones.

**Challenge:** I have this formula which works well. However, it includes the blank value which I want to exclude and I couldn't seem to figure out to adjust the formula. I included the output of the formula below. I tried rethinking the formula using JOIN or CONCATENATE but kept hitting the 50000 character limit error.

=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(","&'Paste Raw Data here'!L2:L,,5000000)),",")))))

[image: Output of the formula above]

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

By making use of `SPLIT`'s default option to remove empty entries, I think your formula can be as simple as

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",A:A),",")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Glorfindel, thanks for getting back to me. Much appreciated. The formula you suggested is awesome but I tried it with a bigger data set and got the error,_"Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters."_.

Comment: Bummer ... it might work with a more complicated formula like yours but I'm not too familiar. It might even be a Google Sheets formula isn't the right tool for the job and you'll need some JavaScript programming in the form of a Google Apps Script.

Comment: That is looking to be the case. No worries and thank you again. Appreciate the time you took out to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a blank second argument for QUERY use "select * where Col1 is not null". The resulting formula is:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(","&'Paste Raw Data here'!L2:L,"select * where Col1 is not null",5000000)),",")))))`